# Security Issue in my Mail-Function. What could it be?

Tags: php

i used a simple php mail function on my Website for several weeks. Today it started sending SPAM and i dont know whats the issue.

Im using the Honeypot-Method and I dont allow sending the form when the user spent less than 3 seconds on the form. 
Here is my php code for processing the form:

```
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $name = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST["name"]));
        $email = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST["email"]));
        $message = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST["message"]));
        $phone = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST["phone"]));
        $time = $_POST["time"];
        $timenow = time();
        $time_difference = $timenow - $time;

    // FILL OUT ALL FORMDATA
        if ($name == "" OR $email == "" OR $message == "" OR $phone == "") {
            $error_message = "Bitte füllen Sie alle Felder aus!";
        }

        if (!isset($error_message)) {
            foreach( $_POST as $value ){
                if( stripos($value,'Content-Type:') !== FALSE ){
                    $error_message = "Es gab ein Problem bei der Dateneingabe. ";
                }
            }

        }
        // HONEYPOT
        if(!isset($error_message) && $_POST["adress"] != "") {
            $error_message = "Netter Versuch!";
        }
        // TIMESTAMP_CHECK
        if($time_difference < 3) {
            $error_message = "Zu schnell";
        }

}
if (!isset($error_message) && isset($name)){EMAILSENDING STUFF}
```

The rest is simple use of the famous phpmailer and a simple html-form. Is there an issue I am not seeing? Or how else could they make use of my site?

Comment: Maybe the bad-intented user is crafting the 'time' parameter in the POST request you recieve. You may want to add complexity to the time transmission

Comment: Oh okay, thank you for the Info. Im gonne check how to prevent that!

Comment: You could always sign the timestamp with an HMAC before embedding it in the form. Or, instead of reading it from the $_POST array, you could store it in $_SESSION.

Comment: user submits time=0, you do `now() - 0`, and get a huge difference. Never **EVER** round-trip a value like that through the client. you should be storing the page load time in $_SESSION, which is out of reach of the user.

Comment: Thanks everybody for the comments. Really helped me a lot since I am a beginner! I will fix this now.

Comment: @Marc B your comment is the most complete, you deserve the credits for the answer.

Comment: I would give him the credit but its not possible for a comment, is it?

Comment: Not :D He has to write the answer